# Fragmented packets reception delayed using Scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, packet-sniffers

I'm using Scapy (2.5.0) and Python (3.11.5) in order to sniff packets from a specific application.
In order to do so, i wrote the following (simplified, but the problem still occurs with this piece of code)

```py
from scapy.all import *

def callback(packet):
    load: bytes = bytes(packet[TCP].payload)
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    ip_id = int(ip_layer.id)
    print(ip_id, len(load))

sniff(filter='ip and src host xx.xx.xx.xx',prn=callback)
```

The source has to sometimes send a lot of data. To do so, it's sending two packets (ore more) with the data split.
I correctly receive and print the first one, but the second one is only printed when a third packet is received, which gives something like that :

```
packet_1 received:
    load: b"a lot of data that needs to b"
    ip_id: 1
...
...
some time elapsed
...
...
packet_2 received:
    load: b"e split in several packets\x00"
    ip_id: 2
packet_3 received:
    load: b"data that has no connection with the two previous packets\x00"
    ip_id: 3
```

The application I want to sniff from is correctly receiving both packets "at the same time" because it shows consistent data. I think the application is using the `\x00` end byte to join splited data.

Could the problem come from the first packet load that doesn't end by `\x00` ? Am I missing something ? Is that a known issue of Scapy ?